# network computers renamed after Yosemite install

Tags: network, macos

Yosemite install (from Mavericks) has automatically changed the names of my network computers as shown in the Finder sidebar. For example, *my name IMac* now displays as *my name iMac(2).* My two additional Mac Airs are displaying the same problem.

I have tried changing the computer names in System Preferences (sharing/computer name/edit) to no effect with or without rebooting.

How can I return to the original computer names?

Comment: A clean install would do that, an update shouldn't. Which was it?

Comment: A clean install *shouldn't* do that either, but I'm having the same problem on both a clean install and an update (as soon as I updated to GM3, which is funny…)

Comment: This was not a clean install. I installed over Mavericks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE 3:** Updating to 10.10.4 fixes this problem. In this point release `discoveryd` is replaced by the previously ousted `mDNSResponder`.

*The originally supplied workaround follows...*

There is a bug between Yosemite (the daemon `discoveryd`) and sleep servers. These servers reside in Apple TVs and Airports and act as a proxy for a sleeping machine. For now the only fix seems to be:

- On your computer, go to **System Preferences --> Energy Saver**, and untick *"Wake for network access"* (or maybe it is *"Wake for Wi-Fi access"*, I think it depends on your interface type).
- Shut down your Apple TV/s and/or Airport/s.
- On your computer, go to **System Preferences --> Sharing**, and rename it as you wish.
- Reboot your computer and check that the name change has stuck (a reboot is probably not necessary but I did so for good measure).
- Power-up your Apple TV/s and/or Airport/s.

I no longer have the incrementing computer name problem, unless I re-enable *"Wake for network access"*.

**UPDATE 1:** Updating to OS X 10.10.1 (and Apple TV to 7.0.2) didn't help.

**UPDATE 2:** Whilst improved, it's still broken in OS X 10.10.3. But the buggy daemon `discoveryd` has apparently been replaced in the 10.10.4 beta by the previously ousted `mDNSResponder`. So here's hoping it's fixed in the next release. Source: [*9to5Mac*](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/26/apple-drops-discoveryd-in-latest-os-x-beta-following-months-of-complaints-about-network-issues-with-yosemite/).

Comment: Thanks. This worked. And it was immediate; no need to wait a day. I've reported it as a bug to Apple.

Comment: The fix was temporary. I can still edit the computer name in prefs/sharing, but replication of the computers continues. I now have iMac, iMac(2) and iMac(3) representing a single computer.

Comment: Sorry about that. Perhaps it was just a coincidence that it worked for me.

Comment: After making the above comment yesterday, I re-enabled "Wake for network access", and this morning I woke to find my computer name changed to "MacBook (2)". So there maybe something there---or it could still be a coincidence.

Comment: This person here claims to have a fix:

[http://ispire.me/fix-yosemite-rtc-alarm-wakeup-issue/](http://ispire.me/fix-yosemite-rtc-alarm-wakeup-issue/)

Namely:

`sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :ProgramArguments: string --no-namechange" /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist`

Although I'm not willing to try it. This seems to be a treatment for the symptom, not the disease.

Comment: Yes, "wake for network access" seems to be the culprit. I now have it turned off and no replication since. Thanks for the nteresting fix in the link you posted, but I'm reluctant to be an early adopter.

Answer (score 1):

Goto System Preferences/Sharing. That's where you can change your computer name.

Comment: As I said in my original question, that's the first thing I did and it didn't work.

Comment: This "solution" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

1. Rename the Macbook to a new name (System Preferences > Sharing): e.g. Jimmy
2. Restart Time Capsule (Applications > Utilities > AirPort Utility)
3. Make sure there are no identical names in Capsule's connected devices (the red box in diagram below)
4. Rename the Macbook back to original name

   [image]