# Why does Yosemite add a number to my system name and how do I stop it?

Tags: macos

I named my system "Foob" on my 2012 MacBook Pro. Yosemite has renamed it "Foob (4)".  I wasn't sure where that "(4)" came from so I renamed it back to "Foob" in the Sharing Preferences. But, I looked today and it's now at "Foob (2)"

Why is it doing this? How can I stop it?

Comment: try giving it a minimum 4 character name

Comment: @Buscar웃 i don't think it is a character issue since the default name is usually more than 4, "Macintosh HD"

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389). (I don't have the reputation to mark this as a duplicate.)