# Multiple empty Chrome/Google setup volumes in root Finder folder

Tags: finder, google-chrome

[image]

Unknown Reason for Excessive repetitive removable volumes with either no files inside or inaccessible directories. I have been getting these artifacts as seen in the image since installing OS X Yosemite. Very mysterious. Anyone with similar errors or with an explaination, or even better - a solution, I would be most grateful to hear from you.

Thanks.

Comment: How many  times did you click on download?

Comment: I removed the portion of your question dealing with "Computer Name (2)" etc. Please try to stick to one question per topic - in this case, they aren't related. The "Computer Name (2)" issue has an answer [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389/157114#157114).

Comment: @Buscar웃 The OP didn't click to download anything. These are being generated automatically by Chrome somehow. I am having the same issue and have had Chrome installed for years.

Comment: Try the Google uninstaller in /Library/Application Support/Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem, though I haven't seen the Chrome Canary folders. I've tried two things now (one in the last few minutes, so let's see if it works this time).

First, open Applications > Utilities > Terminal and copy/paste the following:

```
cd /tmp
sudo rm -rf 2014*
```

At this point you will be prompted for a password. Enter the password you use to login to your Mac.

Then copy/paste this line:

```
open .
```

You should have a Finder window popup. On the sidebar, click on your computer's name and make sure that you don't see any of the Google/Chrome folders.

Second, uninstall the Google Voice and Video plugin. It can be reinstalled if needed in the future, but the uninstall/reinstall process seems to prevent these volumes from showing up again for some people.

Again in Terminal, copy/paste the following:

```
/Library/Application\ Support/Google/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller.app/Contents/MacOS/GoogleVoiceAndVideoUninstaller
```

Press Enter and a dock icon should appear, along with a small window requesting credentials. Enter your Mac login password again and after a minute, it should tell you that Google Voice and Video was uninstalled.

You may have luck with uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome Canary if this didn't fix those folders.