# Console log flooded with discoveryd errors. How can I make them stop (not just hide them)?

Tags: ios, network, macos

They are 3,500 out of the 4,000 of the latest messages. They are always of the form:

```
1/5/15 1:07:38.307 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[73] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:40.487 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[68] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:40.489 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[70] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:40.911 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[73] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:42.668 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[73] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:43.099 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[76] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:45.281 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[68] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:45.963 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[70] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:48.062 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[73] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:49.151 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[68] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:50.250 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[68] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
1/5/15 1:07:51.345 PM discoveryd[49]: Basic Sockets Couldn't set IP_BOUND_IF on socket fd[70] scopeID[11] errno[22] result[-1]
```

And so on. The output of lsof -d on the file descriptors in the error messages (68, 70, 73) is:

```
13:12:35 BigG ~ $ sudo lsof -d 70
COMMAND    PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
UserEvent   17           root   70r   DIR                1,4     3638 16936208 /private/var/log
Little      39           root   70   PIPE 0xc31978735fec6a0b    16384          
discovery   49 _mdnsresponder   70u  IPv4 0xc3197873535be7db      0t0      UDP *:60078
filecoord  229           root   70r   DIR                1,4      102 17141816 /Applications/Messages.app
cloudd     237         george   70u  unix 0xc319787357d38073      0t0          ->0xc319787357d38393
com.apple 6884         george   70r   CHR               11,0 0t147584      577 /dev/random
Mail      6916         george   70u  unix 0xc319787357d366ab      0t0          ->0xc319787357d54a9b
13:12:54 BigG ~ $ sudo lsof -d 68
COMMAND    PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
UserEvent   17           root   68r   DIR                1,4     2278 16936222 /Library
Little      39           root   68   PIPE 0xc31978735fec695b    16384          
discovery   49 _mdnsresponder   68u  IPv6 0xc319787358001583      0t0      UDP *:56376
filecoord  229           root   68r   DIR                1,4      170 18984735 /Users/george/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~mail/Data/MailData
Mail      6916         george   68u  IPv4 0xc31978735c27fb4b      0t0      TCP 172.20.10.2:65427->17.172.34.90:imaps (ESTABLISHED)
Google    7531         george   68u   REG                1,4    45056  2751867 /Users/george/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Shortcuts
13:13:01 BigG ~ $ sudo lsof -d 73
COMMAND    PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
Little      39           root   73   PIPE 0xc31978735fec72fb    16384          
discovery   49 _mdnsresponder   73u  IPv6 0xc31978735694dfb3      0t0      UDP *:56847
filecoord  229           root   73r   DIR                1,4     1224 18983081 /Users/george/Library/Mobile Documents
Mail      6916         george   73u   REG                1,4      512 19235471 /private/var/folders/hj/3s2lw9xx18zf5gx13b5wkp0c0000gn/T/com.apple.mail/etilqs_Q2RlNGOuSx38TFf
Google    7531         george   73u   REG                1,4    18432  2752345 /Users/george/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Login Data
```

This flood does not happen on my home WiFi, but is occurring while using an iPhone (iOS 8.1.2) plugged into the USB port AND over Bluetooth PAN networking on a MBP Retina (10.10.1).

In the past the file descriptors in the error messages were different, but it was always three different ones.

Answer (score 1):

Long term, the way to fix this is to opt in to sharing your logs and crashes with Apple and reporting this as a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com

Short term, you can choose a different network (probably a bad option) or suppress IPv6 (also probably bad long term) or try and disable the error logging entirely (probably bad).

4k lines of error messages isn't really a flood on any OS X hardware in the last dozen years. Even 400k messages a day isn't any significant load on the filesystem or the CPU. Is there something else you're trying to do where these messages are causing grief?

Comment: Why do you suspect IPv6? When connecting via iPhone USB the option to change TCP/IP settings isn't present (no Advanced option) so I don't know if I can even turn off IPv6 for that method. And 4,000 entries is merely the limit in the "All Messages" query in Console. It is actually about 90% of ALL the entries generally, in the older log files as well. If you notice, they are about 1 second apart so ~60/minute. I can hide the sender "discoveryd" but that is not a solution, but hiding the problem.

Comment: @geoO You're right - I didn't realize the console query pooped out at 4k so that's a very real downside. Have you seen this thread with people trying to neuter discoveryd to avoid host name changes? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/

Comment: 10.10.1 fixed the name changes, but not the discoveryd log entries.

Answer (score 0):

When i get these messages any DNS lookups made using discoveryd fail (Chrome and nslookup work). Workaround:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist
```

Comment: Thanks. That's clever, but I'd like to identify a cause. Still haven't.

Comment: Sure me too, but at least that gets you running again. I made an alias in zsh