# How to refuse DHCP Server to change my hostname?

Tags: network, airport, osx-server, dns

I was not able to refuse changing my hostname by DHCP Server on Mac Book.
None of these solutions below worked for me:

- [How can I stop Mac OS X overriding my hostname when I receive a DHCP request on Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/49891/how-can-i-stop-mac-os-x-overriding-my-hostname-when-i-receive-a-dhcp-request-on)
- [Mac refusing to change hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087637/mac-refusing-to-change-hostname)
- [Computer name keeps changing (deleting files)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389)

After deleting the files as suggested from the Apple engineer it retrieved a new hostname and a new ip. But it wasn't a static hostname. Creating the file /etc/hostconfig doesn't work neither.

I mean come on, that's a well known feature and it should work. Poorly it doesn't for now. I'm sure there must be a solution for this.

As the server we are using a Mac Mini with built-in DNS and DHCP. My Mac Book's system is macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Edit: From the 3rd link, the Apple engineer suggested to delete the following three files in `/Libray/Preferences/SystemConfiguration`:

```
com.apple.airport.preferences.plist
NetworkInterfaces.plist
preferences.plist
```

Comment: Related [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40734/why-is-my-host-name-wrong-at-the-terminal-prompt-when-connected-to-a-public-wifi)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It took a LOT of Googling and digging to get this, but I finally found a solution that works. DHCP overrides the `LocalHostName` system property, but not the `HostName` property. By default the `HostName` is not set in macOS Sierra, so you can set it as well as `LocalHostName` and `ComputerName` using `scutil`:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName yourcomputername
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName yourcomputername
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "Your Computer name"
```

The `HostName` property appears to be permanent. `LocalHostName` can still be overridden, but it won't override `HostName` once it's set.

Comment: Well, I think both solutions would do it. As I prefer the bash, I used your solution. The hostname isnot changed anymore after a few reboots.

Comment: This only works temporarily for me. A few days later I'm back to "Thomas David Baker's Macbook Pro". Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Open `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.discoveryd.plist` with Xcode and add to the ‘ProgramArguments’ array with the string `--no-namechange`. Save the file and restart the machine.

[image]

Comment: com.apple.discoveryd.plist as well as /usr/libexec/discoveryd only exist in some Yosemite releases (10.10.0-10.10.3)....

Comment: This file doesn't exist on macOS 11.3.1 – is there a new equivalent?