# What is changing ComputerName?

Tags: network, macos

So there is a this thing called *computer name* that can be set either via Preferences -> Sharing, or sudo scutil --set ComputerName "My Name"

When I use

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "My Name"
```

and then use

```
sudo scutil --get ComputerName
```

I get something stupid like "My Name (2)". My question is: What is changing the name?

Because there is a question [Computer name keeps changing OSX 10.10 (14A389)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153080/computer-name-keeps-changing-osx-10-10-14a389) which asks how to overcome automatic change, and some hah are being suggested.

I don't want to hack things, I want to know what is changing the name, so then in perspective I can just kill it.

Comment: Are you running CrashPlan? I found that kept reverting my hostname. If not, check other 3rd party apps which might be keeping ahold of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Updating to 10.10.4 fixes this problem. In this point release `discoveryd` is replaced by the previously ousted `mDNSResponder`.

*The originally supplied answer follows...*

This is caused by an interaction with a daemon called `discoveryd` (that is present in Yosemite OS X 10.10.0 to 10.10.3) and the sleep proxies that are present within Apple TVs and Airports.

I outlined a workaround [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152340/network-computers-renamed-after-yosemite-install/152653#152653); which is basically disabling *"Wake for Network Access"*, which is also suggested in the post you linked to. You could also stop using your Apple TV/s and Apple Airport/s if you are in a position that allows you to do so.

[*9to5Mac* reports](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/26/apple-drops-discoveryd-in-latest-os-x-beta-following-months-of-complaints-about-network-issues-with-yosemite/) that `discoveryd` has been dropped in OS X 10.10.4 beta and replaced with the previously ousted `mDNSResponder` daemon. So this problem should be fixed in OS X 10.10.4.