# Remove Duplicate Shared Computers

Tags: network, finder, macos, airport

After my upgrade to Yosemite, I am seeing a couple of extra shared computers in my finder sidebar.

There are two additional computers that seem to be copies, based on their naming, having (#) appended to the computer name.

After checking all computers on my network, I can see that this issue is not only on one machine, they all show the same list. Additionally, I can verify the duplicates do not exist as I cannot connect to them.

I have tried the following:

- Renaming my machines
- Disabling / Re-enabling sharing
- Restarting All Machines / Performing all necessary updates
- Clearing recent servers from each computer
- Restarting Airport Extreme
- Relaunching Finder on each machine

Here is a screenshot displaying what I see in my Finder window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Updating to 10.10.4 fixes this problem. In this point release `discoveryd` is replaced by the previously ousted `mDNSResponder`.

*The originally supplied answer follows...*

This is caused by an interaction with a daemon called `discoveryd` (that is present in Yosemite OS X 10.10.0 to 10.10.3) and the sleep proxies that are present within Apple TVs and Airports.

I outlined a workaround [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152340/network-computers-renamed-after-yosemite-install/152653#152653); which is basically disabling *"Wake for Network Access"*.

[*9to5Mac* reports](http://9to5mac.com/2015/05/26/apple-drops-discoveryd-in-latest-os-x-beta-following-months-of-complaints-about-network-issues-with-yosemite/) that `discoveryd` has been dropped in OS X 10.10.4 beta and replaced with the previously ousted `mDNSResponder` daemon. So this problem should be fixed in OS X 10.10.4.